# Right overflowed even if I use scrollDirection axis.horizontal

Tags: flutter

I got this problem to my ui at the bottom where users see their reviews. It appears this overflowed thing and I don't know what I should add to make this disappear . I don't have a scaffold to use      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false . The app is made with flutter , what I should change?

return ListView.builder(

```
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Container(
                                    width: 200,
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 8, bottom: 8, right: 12),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                                          blurRadius: 2,
                                          spreadRadius: 1)
                                    ], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Row(
                                          children: [
                                            CircleAvatar(
                                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                                  snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                                      .data["avatarUrl"]),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(width: 8),
                                            Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                                .data["name"],style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        _buildRatingStars(snapshot.data
                                            .documents[index].data["rating"]),
                                        Text(snapshot
                                            .data.documents[index].data["text"])
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  );
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with the `ListView.builder` but with the fixed width of your `Container`.

Try to remove the `width: 200`:

```
return ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Container(
      width: 200,
```

Comment: Same, same, but different. You have to find what is constraining the `height` of your `ListView`.

Comment: It should not be added at the last text somehow an Expanded?

Comment: Can you provide details about the structure around your `ListView`?